# How can I move a folder to another folder with all its underlying files and folders?

Tags: powershell

Source Folder:

```
C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\200003_QWE
```

Destination Folder:

```
C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\200002_QWE
```

The Source Folder `200003_QWE` should be moved to `Z_Transfered`.

Which is moved below `Z_Transfered` the folder `200003_QWE` with its subordinates and files.

I have tried:

```
New-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2    \Z_Transfered\200002_QWE" -ItemType "directory"
Move-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\200002_QWE\" -Destination "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\200002_QWE"
```

It shifts my folder like that but then I have two folders with the same name, how can I solve this?

Looks like this:

```
C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\200002_QWE\200002_QWE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
Move-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\200002_QWE\" -Destination "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\"
```

Comment: unfortunately gives an error message: Move-Item : Eine Datei kann nicht erstellt werden, wenn sie bereits vorhanden ist.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Move-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\20000 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\test\old\Dat...de2\200002_QWE\:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: Use the force switch: 
Move-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\200002_QWE\" -Destination "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\" -force

Ideally the folder is not there when the code works I assume.

Comment: it just moves the file too `Z_Transfered`.

Comment: I was under the impression that you were trying to move a folder to a different folder. Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for the help.
I solved the problem.
The problem was a backslash at the end of the target path.

Solution:

```
New-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\" -ItemType "directory"
Move-Item -Path "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\200002_QWE\" -Destination "C:\test\old\Data\Werkstatt\06. Aufträge\Kunde2\Z_Transfered\200002_QWE" -force
```